# Simple Linux desktop navigation system for tracking a drone

Tags: software-recommendations, linux, navigation

Trying to build my own ground control station (GCS) for different drones I have.  One is a boat and the other a plane.  I have looked at the GCS's available and they are great, but I want to do something much simpler.  I really only need.want to put a red dot on a GeoTiff, stored natively on the GCS.

The TDMA radio is Ethernet based and the drones have GPSd running on their Raspberry Pi, which publish to TCP port 2947.

What packages or applications would you recommend to achieve this ?

Should I look at hacking GPSDrive or QGIS.  QGIS looks great, but has lots of bells and whistles.

Is there something simpler ?

Would prefer to avoid anything written in Java, preferring C, Java Script and Python.

Comment: For software recommendations I think you should consider the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest would be to build some web application.

Basic approach could be something like: 
Write a small program in any language pushing gps points from gpsd to Postgis.
Put PostgREST in front of postgis (http://postgrest.com)
Make a web client request new points every second. Easiest is to construct geoJSON in PostGIS. Can build both simple points and lines of tracs from all your drones from lets say last 5 mins.
Render in Leaflet or OpenLayers.

You could also build more advanced thing with web sockets to get it more "real time" of course.

I think itnia easier to put together some stack like this than finding something that.ä works out of the box. And hacking desktop solutions will be more challenging I guess.